# Finding the primary key field for Hibernate entity

Tags: hibernate, primary-key

Is it possible for us to find what are the primary key fields for a Hibernate entity programmatically (similar to JPA's `PersistenceUnitUtil`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SessionFactory` provides an method called [getClassMetadata()](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hibernate/hibernate-3.6.0.Final/org/hibernate/metadata/ClassMetadata.html) to get the meta-data object  for a class (i.e. [ClassMetadata](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hibernate/hibernate-3.6.0.Final/org/hibernate/metadata/ClassMetadata.html))

To get the name of the identifier  properties of an entity , use [ClassMetadata.getIdentifierPropertyName()](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hibernate/hibernate-3.6.0.Final/org/hibernate/metadata/ClassMetadata.html#getIdentifierPropertyName%28%29)

```
ClassMetadata employeeMeta =  sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(Employee.class);
System.out.println("Name of the identifier property of the employee entity :" + employeeMeta .getIdentifierPropertyName());
```

To get the value of the identifier  properties for an managed entity  instance , use [ClassMetadata.getIdentifier(Object entity, SessionImplementor session)](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hibernate/hibernate-3.6.0.Final/org/hibernate/metadata/ClassMetadata.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.Object,%20org.hibernate.engine.SessionImplementor%29)

For example :
Suppose you have a managed entity instance that is loaded from a session :

```
List<Employee> employeeList = (List<Employee>)session.createQuery("from Employee where gender ='F'").list();
ClassMetadata employeeMeta = session.getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(Employee.class);
for (Employee employee : employeeList ) {
    System.out.println("Value of the Primary key:" + employeeMeta.getIdentifier(employee , session) );
}
```

Comment: As I was just typing in my own answer to that I have figured it out and by the same manner you (@KenChan) have stated here, I saw your post coming through! Thanks!

Comment: What type is session here? I don't have anything like this in my code that I can tell (no uses of getSessionFactory)

Answer (score 4):

I realize this question is now more than two years old and already answered, but it's between the first 10 results Google finds for "hibernate get primarykey fields" (and probably other similar queries) so I think it's important to add this information here.

Recently, I was working on a Java system and I needed to get the primary key (s) of a table, however, all I had was the Hibernate `Configuration` object and the name of the table.

While Johanna's answer is very simple and helped me, I found out it doesn't work as expected for tables with a composite primary key, as only one of the fields that composes the primary key is found.

I dug up into the `PersistentClass` properties and have found a way of dealing with both cases of primary key (composite and single):

```
/**
 * Maps a table's primary key to a Map<String, String> where the keys are the names of
 * the fields that compose the primary key and the values are the type names of said
 * fields.
 * 
 * @param tableName The name of the which for which the primary keys will be gotten
 * @param hibernateConfiguration The Hibernate configuration for the database
 *     IMPORTANT: $tableName must be already mapped in the configuration.
 * @returns A map with the fields names as keys and their types' names as values.
 */
public static Map<String, String> retrievePrimaryKeys(String tableName, Configuration hibernateConfiguration) {
    hibernateConfiguration.buildMappings();

    HashMap<String, String> primaryKeys = new HashMap<>();
    PersistentClass tableMapping = hibernateConfiguration.getClassMapping(tableName);

    Object tableIdentifier =  tableMapping.getIdentifier();

    if(tableIdentifier instanceof SimpleValue) {

        // Whenever the identifier is a SimpleValue, it means that the table has only one PrimaryKey. 
        // At this point, it's assumed that the primary key was mapped using the <id> element in the mapping XML file.
        // We iterate over the columns below, because it's a safer way of handling this thing.

        SimpleValue tableIdentifierValue = (SimpleValue) tableIdentifier;
        Iterator primaryKeysIterator = tableIdentifierValue.getColumnIterator();

        while(primaryKeysIterator.hasNext()) {
            Column primaryKey = (Column) primaryKeysIterator.next();
            SimpleValue primaryKeyValue = (SimpleValue) primaryKey.getValue();
            primaryKeys.put(primaryKey.getName(), primaryKeyValue.getTypeName());
        }
    }
    else if (tableIdentifier instanceof Component)
    {
        // Whenever the identifier is a Component, it means that the table has a composite primary key.
        // At this point, it's assumed that the primary key was mapped using the <composite-id> element in the mapping XML file

        Component identifiers = (Component) tableIdentifier;
        Iterator identifierIterator = identifiers.getPropertyIterator();

        while(identifierIterator.hasNext()) {
            Property identifier = (Property) identifierIterator.next();
            SimpleValue value = (SimpleValue) identifier.getValue();

            primaryKeys.put(identifier.getName(), value.getTypeName());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // If the program reaches this point, it means that Hibernate hates you and there's a third unknown way of declaring and getting a table's primary key.
    }

    return primaryKeys;
}
```

I must add that Java is not my specialty, as neither is Hibernate, so there *might* be a better and more concise way of handling this (I hope so, at least), but I can't find it.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at `PersistentClass` (you get it with `configuration.getClassMapping(<classname>)`). There `getIdentifierProperty()` or `getKeyClosureIterator()` might be useful - depending of your needs.